# Creating of new columns in pandas.DataFrame using apply() function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like:

```
          A    B  
'2010-01-01'  10  20   
'2010-02-01'  20  30  
'2010-03-01'  30  10
```

I need to apply some function for every columns and create new columns in this DataFrame with special name.

```
               A   B A1 B1  
'2010-01-01'  10  20 20 40  
'2010-02-01'  20  30 40 60  
'2010-03-01'  30  10 60 20
```

So I need to make two additional columns with names `A1` and `B2` based on columns `A` and `B` ( like name `A1  = str(A) + str(1)`) by multiplying by two. Is it possible to do this using `DataFrame.apply()` or other construction?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `join` to do the combining:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30], "B": [20, 30, 10]})
>>> df
    A   B
0  10  20
1  20  30
2  30  10
>>> df * 2
    A   B
0  20  40
1  40  60
2  60  20
>>> df.join(df*2, rsuffix='1')
    A   B  A1  B1
0  10  20  20  40
1  20  30  40  60
2  30  10  60  20
```

where you could replace `df*2` with `df.apply(your_function)` if you liked.

Answer (score 3):

I would skip the `apply` method and just define the columns directly.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30], "B": [20, 30, 10]})
for col in df.columns:
    df[col+"1"] = df[col] * 2
```

Not as elegant as DSM's solution. But for whatever reason I avoid `apply` unless I really need it.

Comment: BY avoiding the `join` this also has the nice benefit of not having to reassign the dataframe.