# How to properly apply a lambda function into a pandas data frame column

Tags: pandas, lambda

I have a pandas data frame, `sample`, with one of the columns called `PR` to which am applying a lambda function as follows:

```
sample['PR'] = sample['PR'].apply(lambda x: NaN if x < 90)
```

I then get the following syntax error message:

```
sample['PR'] = sample['PR'].apply(lambda x: NaN if x < 90)
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that for most operations, `apply` is not needed at all. Please use vectorized operations instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73643899/19123103) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62968313/19123103) for more info.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
sample['PR'] = sample['PR'].mask(sample['PR'] < 90, np.nan)
```

Another solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
sample.loc[sample['PR'] < 90, 'PR'] = np.nan
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sample = pd.DataFrame({'PR':[10,100,40] })
print (sample)
    PR
0   10
1  100
2   40

sample['PR'] = sample['PR'].mask(sample['PR'] < 90, np.nan)
print (sample)
      PR
0    NaN
1  100.0
2    NaN
```

```
sample.loc[sample['PR'] < 90, 'PR'] = np.nan
print (sample)
      PR
0    NaN
1  100.0
2    NaN
```

EDIT:

Solution with `apply`:

```
sample['PR'] = sample['PR'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x < 90 else x)
```

**Timings** `len(df)=300k`:

```
sample = pd.concat([sample]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [853]: %timeit sample['PR'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x < 90 else x)
10 loops, best of 3: 102 ms per loop

In [854]: %timeit sample['PR'].mask(sample['PR'] < 90, np.nan)
The slowest run took 4.28 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 3.71 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 29):

You need to add `else` in your lambda function. Because you are telling what to do in case your condition(here x < 90) is met, but you are not telling what to do in case the condition is not met.

```
sample['PR'] = sample['PR'].apply(lambda x: 'NaN' if x < 90 else x)
```