# looping over rows, columns, and perform operations on the columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[showing list of animals - each row represents a location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt12u.png)

I want to loop through a 761,000 rows by 25 columns excel document, for the each row

1. count columns with values>0 and store in a column called count
2. for the values > 0, add them and store in a new column called animals_per_location
3. return the names of the column title that has values greater than zero

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiV48.png)

Comment: what did you try ? can you post some code ?

Comment: Could you also create a minimum input dataset and expected output from this minimum set.  See [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428218/how-to-properly-apply-a-lambda-function-into-a-pandas-data-frame-column

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html

Comment: actually, you do not have to loop over the rows. Take a look into 10 Minutes to pandas. This should be possible by logical indexing and very simple data manipulation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html