# How to generate random values including NaN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I would like to generate random floating number including `NaN` in a Data Frame with `np.random.randn`

Comment: What would like to be the distribution of NaNs? Eg. NaN with probability p and uniform random with probability 1-p?

Comment: I would like 2/7 NaNs.

Comment: I suggest to check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962104/pandas-how-can-i-use-the-apply-function-for-a-single-column)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate an array of random floats, then create a mask with `np.choice` using `p` to allow you to set a weight for the number of `NaN` to include.

Something like:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(20)
mask = np.random.choice([1, 0], a.shape, p=[.1, .9]).astype(bool)
a[mask] = np.nan
```

Result:

```
array([ 1.2769248 ,  0.5949608 , -1.38006737,  0.3582266 , -1.852884  ,
        0.81121663, -1.45830948,  0.03117856,  0.54509948,  1.22019729,
        1.71643753,         nan, -0.32470862, -0.77604474,  0.76698089,
       -0.47863251,         nan, -0.33308071, -0.32026717,  1.8493752 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a DataFrame you can use `apply`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = np.zeros(10) # or get data from somewhere else
p = 2/7
df.a.apply(lambda x: np.nan if np.random.rand() < p else np.random.rand())
```