# Pandas: shorten notation for simple operations on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Is there a good way to shorten this:

```
df.a = df.a / 2
df.b = df.b / 2
df.c = df.c / 2
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962104/pandas-how-can-i-use-the-apply-function-for-a-single-column), something like

```
df[['A','B','C']] = df[['A', 'B','C']].apply(lambda a: a / 2)
```

should be avoided.

Comment: I think it should be avoided because the operation won't be vectorized anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do it like this

```
df[['A','B','C']] = df[['A','B','C']]/2
```

Comment: Yes you should not be using ```apply``` when you can easily perform the vectorized operations!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to take advantage of vectorization. 

`df[['A','B','C']]/2`