# How to insert value in df based on function output from another column value

Tags: pandas

I have 2 columns in my dataframe:
ip,geoIP

I want to loop through my df and perform a user defined function to geolocate an IP and fill the geoIP column with the return value from the function.

How can i populate the column geoIP with the output from my user defined function which takes the input of the value of the column ip?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? This seems like a basic, trivial Pandas question, no? Why haven't you read the docs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26886653/11301900

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34962104/11301900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```
def user_defined_function(x):
  #add your code here


df['geoIP'] = df['ip'].apply(user_defined_function)
```

Comment: Thank you - your way was so much easier than how i ended up doing it.

for i in df3.ip.unique():
...     a = geoLocateIP(i)
...     df3.loc[df3.ip==i,'IPGeo'] = a