# Apply function over a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am working on Pandas and I am struggling to create a new column with information from an API over the rows of my dataframe.

The "location" column I want to iterate is a Series of dictionaries like this:

```
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-0.1394759, 51.5170385]}
```

My function:

```
def starbucks(df):
    API_key = os.getenv('API_KEY')
    lat = list(df["location"])[1]["coordinates"][1]
    lon = list(df["location"])[1]["coordinates"][0]
    base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?"
    endpoint = "query=starbucks&location={0},{1}&radius=1000&key={2}".format(lat, lon, API_key)
    res = requests.get(base_url+endpoint).json()
```

How I am implementing the apply function (currently with a `'location', 'occurred at index 61'` error):

```
sample['testing'] = sample.apply(lambda x: starbucks(x["location"]), axis=1)
```

I've read some posts regarding the apply function and the documentation, but I am still missing something.

Help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: How can I use the apply() function for a single column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962104/pandas-how-can-i-use-the-apply-function-for-a-single-column)

Comment: Why are you casting the columns to lists? `The "location" column I want to iterate is a Series of dictionaries like this:` Why not separate the data into multiple columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is expecting a data frame, but you are passing a value to it. I think your function should be:

```
def starbucks(val):
    API_key = os.getenv('API_KEY')
    lat = list(val)[1]["coordinates"][1]
    lon = list(val)[1]["coordinates"][0]
    base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?"
    endpoint = "query=starbucks&location={0},{1}&radius=1000&key={2}".format(lat, lon, API_key)
    res = requests.get(base_url+endpoint).json()
    return res
```

Here's another article that will give you more examples of how to use apply:
[Pandas: How can I use the apply() function for a single column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962104/pandas-how-can-i-use-the-apply-function-for-a-single-column)