# How do I apply the function to tweets dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, arabic, data-cleaning, tweets

**This function is for cleaning arabic tweets in dataframe pandas**

```
def clean_tweets(s):
    s= s.replace("RT",'')
    r = re.compile(r"(?:^|\s)([@#h])(\w+)")
    s=re.sub(r,"",s)
    s = re.sub('[:/.…!"()]', '', s)
    s = re.sub('[a-zA-Z]', '', s)
    s = re.sub('[0-9]', '', s)
    return s
```

**Dataframe contains just one column (Tweets)**

````
Tweets
0 الجنائية" ترفض *- طلب...
1 كورونا" في  @@@#$البيت...
2 طيران الإمارات تت...
3 خلال 24 ساعة.. #### أمري...
4 &&تنقب عن النفط...```
````

**- I need to apply clean_tweets function on tweets (rows in dataframe) ?
   how ?**

Comment: `df['cleaned'] = df['Tweets'].apply(clean_tweets)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: How can I use the apply() function for a single column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962104/pandas-how-can-i-use-the-apply-function-for-a-single-column)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming tweets is a Series, you can do

```
tweets.apply(clean_tweets)
```