# How to use apply and lambda to change a pandas data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

I cannot figure this out. I want to change the "type" column in this dataset to 0/1 values.

```
url = "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/PRNN/pima.tr"
Pima_training = pd.read_csv(url,sep = '\s+')
Pima_training["type"] = Pima_training["type"].apply(lambda x : 1 if x == 'Yes' else 0)
```

I get the following error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
```

Comment: Actually it is not an error, it is a warning as far as I know

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: this code is working fine for me

Comment: your code works for me

Comment: do you know what the warning means? should i be concerned?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

This is a `warning` and won't break your code. This happens when pandas detects  `chained assignment`, which is when you use multiple indexing operations, and there might be ambiguity about whether you are modifying the original df or a copy of the df. Other more experienced programmers have [explained it in depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) in another SO thread, so feel free to give it a read for a further explanation.

In your particular example, you don't need `.apply` at all here (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962104/pandas-how-can-i-use-the-apply-function-for-a-single-column) for why not, but using apply on a single column is very inefficient because it loops over rows internally), and I think it makes more sense to use `.replace` instead, and a pass a dictionary.

```
Pima_training['type'] = Pima_training['type'].replace({"No":0,"Yes":1})
```