# Applying function to pandas column based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df`

```
cur    val
USD    50
GBP    100
EUR    150
```

I am trying to convert all values to GBP:

```
def sales_gbp(df):
    cur = df.cur
    value = df.val

    if cur == 'USD':
        return val*0.72
    elif cur == 'EUR':
        return val*0.85
    else:
        return val
```

```
df['value_GBP'] = df.apply(sales_gbp(df), axis=1)
```

But I get :

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

> ----> 5     if cur == 'USD':

`df.dtypes` return `object` for both `cur` and `val`. I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962104/how-can-i-use-the-apply-function-for-a-single-column) but I still can't apply the function to my `df`.

Comment: Don't pass `df`, do `df.apply(sales_gbp axis=1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest use variable `x` in function for clear it is different variable like original `df`, then dont pass `df` to [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def sales_gbp(x):
    cur = x.cur
    val = x.val

    if cur == 'USD':
        return val*0.72
    elif cur == 'EUR':
        return val*0.85
    else:
        return val

df['value_GBP'] = df.apply(sales_gbp, axis=1)
```

Better is pass `dict` for mapping and for not match values by dict is return `NaN`, so replace them by `1`:

```
d = {'USD':0.72, 'GBP':0.85}
df['value_GBP'] = df['cur'].map(d).fillna(1).mul(df['val'])
print (df)
   cur  val  value_GBP
0  USD   50       36.0
1  GBP  100       85.0
2  EUR  150      150.0
```

Or use `fill_value=1` in [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
d = {'USD':0.72, 'GBP':0.85}
df['value_GBP'] = df['cur'].map(d).mul(df['val'], fill_value=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the series directly:

**Sample data**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'cur': {0: 'USD', 1: 'GBP', 2: 'EUR'}, 'val': {0: 50, 1: 100, 2: 150}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Code**

```
dct = {'GBP': 1, 'USD': 0.72, 'EUR': 0.85}
df['value_GBP'] = df['cur'].map(dct) * df['val']
```

**Output**

```
0     36.0
1    100.0
2    127.5
```