# How to apply a function for each row in the column python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a code like this

```
imdb_dir = '/home/yan/PycharmProjects/NLTK_ML/aclImdb'  
train_dir = os.path.join(imdb_dir, 'train') 
labels = []
texts = []
for label_type in ['neg', 'pos']:

    dir_name = os.path.join(train_dir, label_type)
    for fname in tqdm(os.listdir(dir_name)):

        if fname[-4:] == '.txt':
            # Read the text file and put it in the list
            f = open(os.path.join(dir_name, fname))
            texts.append(f.read())
            f.close()
            # Attach the corresponding label
            if label_type == 'neg':
                labels.append(0)
            else:
                labels.append(1)

max_words = 10000 
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words) 
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts) 
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts) 

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
maxlen = 100 # Make all sequences 100 words long
data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=maxlen)

labels = np.asarray(labels)

indices = np.arange(data.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
data = data[indices]
labels = labels[indices]

training_samples = 20000 
validation_samples = 5000

x_train = data[:training_samples]
y_train = labels[:training_samples]
x_val = data[training_samples: training_samples + validation_samples]
y_val = labels[training_samples: training_samples + validation_samples]

glove_dir = '/home/yan/PycharmProjects/NLTK_ML' # This is the folder with the dataset


embeddings_index = {}
f = open(os.path.join(glove_dir, 'glove.6B.100d.txt')) 

for line in tqdm(f):
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0] # The first value is the word, the rest are the values of the embedding
    embedding = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32') 
    embeddings_index[word] = embedding 
f.close()

all_embs = np.stack(embeddings_index.values())
emb_mean = all_embs.mean() # Calculate mean
emb_std = all_embs.std() # Calculate standard deviation
emb_mean,emb_std

embedding_dim = 100

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
nb_words = min(max_words, len(word_index)) 

embedding_matrix = np.random.normal(emb_mean, emb_std, (nb_words, embedding_dim))

for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i >= max_words:
        continue
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)

    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen, weights = [embedding_matrix], trainable = False))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    epochs=10,
                    batch_size=32,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

def getPositivity(my_text):
    seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([my_text])
    seq = pad_sequences(seq, maxlen=maxlen)
    prediction = model.predict(seq)
    return prediction

df_ticker['prediction'] = df_ticker['text'].apply(lambda text:getPositivity(text))
# print(df_ticker)
df_ticker.to_csv('NLP_ML.csv', index=False)
```

it gives me [[0.45654]]
i have a dataframe

```
                          dt       id  text compare   timestamp
3  2021-04-12 03:17:37+00:00  gu7tiax  riot 60$ call       1  2021-04-12
4  2021-04-12 13:15:04+00:00  gu91gf2  vix       0  2021-04-12
5  2021-04-12 14:22:04+00:00  gu99dqg  tsal to the moon       0  2021-04-12
```

I want to get apply this function for each row in the column
I tried like this
but it outputs only the last row and I want to have all the rows

```
                          dt       id  text   timestamp      prediction
5  2021-04-12 14:22:04+00:00  gu99dqg  tsal to the moon       0  2021-04-12  [[0.29380253]]
```

I thought that the issue is on the last few lines of code where I apply getPositivity function. I tried to apply moview reviews NLTK on the new dataframe. So i tried to applt machine learning on the whole new dataframe but it gives me only one line, when I want to output all the lines with the positivity score.
Appreciate your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use the apply() function for a single column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962104/how-can-i-use-the-apply-function-for-a-single-column)

Comment: I don't know why i get the output only for the last one and not all of them

Comment: did you tried this ?                                                                            
           `df_ticker['prediction'] = df_ticker['text'].apply(lambda text:getPositivity(text))`

Comment: I don't know if this might be the issue <ipython-input-2-5e999be54c3d>:173: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df_ticker['prediction'] = df_ticker['text'].apply(lambda text:getPositivity(text))

Comment: it is just a warning it shouldn't be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the code, but as I don't have the necessary tokenizer packages installed, I couldnt get that to run. Instead, I ran a simpler function below:

```
import tokenizer
my_text = 'any future for evs?'

def getPositivity(my_text):
    prediction = my_text + "??"
    return prediction

df_ticker['prediction'] = df_ticker['text'].apply(getPositivity)
df_ticker
```

and got the output as per the attached image.
I believe the issue lies in the tokenizer side, and not in the apply side.
Could you try running my code and sharing your output?

[image: dataframe]

Alternatively, the warning message you shared in the comments suggests you have a line like this somewhere:

```
df_ticker = df[0:5]
```

(or any other type of restriction on a dataframe)

If this is the case, python occasionally does not like you adding columns to a restriction of the dataframe.

To amend this, you would replace the example I just mentioned with:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df_ticker = df2[0:5]
```

etc.

Gregory

Comment: can i share the whole code with you?

Comment: That's fine by me :)

Comment: yeah sorry that works thank you

Comment: No problem mate!