# How to split a column containing a values using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split

I have a data column containg the values as shown in the image and i want to split them into different columns . Data type of column B is object/string

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | ("apple",123,"six",03-10-2020) |
| 10 | ("banana","two") |
| 5 | ("mango",156,02-10-2020) |

and i want to split it into different columns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbsop.png)

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy if Column B has fixed four values for 'fruit', 'code', 'quantity', and 'date'.
However, the number of values are not fixed here, which makes hard to solve.
I assume that there are three patterns as you exampled and solve the problem, as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column A': [12, 10, 5],
    'Column B': ['("apple",123,"six",03-10-2020)', '("banana","two")', '("mango",156,02-10-2020)']
})

fruits = []
codes = []
quantities = []
dates = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    values = row['Column B'][1:-1].split(',')
    if len(values) == 1:
        fruit, code, quantity, date = values[0], None, None, None
    elif len(values) == 2:
        fruit, code, quantity, date = values[0], None, values[1], None
    elif len(values) == 3:
        fruit, code, quantity, date = values[0], values[1], None, values[2]
    elif len(values) == 4:
        fruit, code, quantity, date = values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]
    else:
        pass
    fruits.append(fruit)
    codes.append(code)
    quantities.append(quantity)
    dates.append(date)

df['fruit'] = pd.Series(fruits)
df['codes'] = pd.Series(codes)
df['quantities'] = pd.Series(quantities)
df['dates'] = pd.Series(dates)
del df['Column B']
print(df)
```

```py
#   Column A     fruit codes quantities       dates
#0        12   "apple"   123      "six"  03-10-2020
#1        10  "banana"  None      "two"        None
#2         5   "mango"   156       None  02-10-2020
```

I assums that if Column B has three values, it would be 'fruit', 'code', and 'date' (for example, "mango",156,02-10-2020), not 'fruit', 'quantity', and 'date'.
You might want to modify my code if your pattern is more varied.

Answer (score 0):

@nik I see one additional challenge here. From you data frame, I see no pattern in you "Column B". So I suggest you to write a function to arrange the tuples in a standard format as show below (For help check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962104/how-can-i-use-the-apply-function-for-a-single-column))

| Old Col B | New Col B |
| --- | --- |
| ("banana","two") | ("banana", None,"two", None) |
| ("mango",156,02-10-2020) | ("mango",156, None,02-10-2020) |

After your data is in acceptable standard format, you use pandas inbuilt function to split your data. Example is below

```
df['New Col B'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "banana" | None | "two" | None |
| "mango" | 156 | None | 02-10-2020 |