# How to Determine Final State of Sequential Entries in a Pandas DataFrame Using Vectorized Operations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with columns representing various attributes of data entries, including a timestamp "dh_processamento_rubrica", a unique identifier "inivalid_iderubrica", and an operation type "operacao". The operations include "inclusao" (insertion), "alteracao" (modification), and "exclusao" (deletion).

For each unique identifier, there can be multiple operations performed, where "alteracao" modifies existing entries created by "inclusao", and "exclusao" removes entries. The modifications can include changing certain attributes (like "codinccp_dadosrubrica") or updating the identifier itself using "inivalid_nova_validade" (in the example below updating "inivalid_iderubrica" from 2019-11-01 to 2019-01-01) in the second row. "dh_processamento_rubrica" is when the operation was performed).

There can only be one entry for each distinct "inivalid_iderubrica", but if it is changed, a new one can later be created with the old value.

Here's a simplified version of my DataFrame:

| codinccp_dadosrubrica | inivalid_iderubrica | inivalid_nova_validade | operacao | dh_processamento_rubrica |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2019-11-01 | NaT | inclusao | 2020-03-18 23:58:14 |
| 11 | 2019-11-01 | 2019-01-01 | alteracao | 2020-05-14 17:27:06 |
| 00 | 2019-11-01 | NaT | inclusao | 2020-06-07 23:46:07 |
| 00 | 2019-01-01 | NaT | alteracao | 2021-07-15 19:57:42 |
| NaN | 2019-11-01 | NaT | exclusao | 2021-08-13 15:31:56 |

Code to generate DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'codinccp_dadosrubrica': ['11', '11', '00', '00', None], 
        'inivalid_iderubrica': [pd.Timestamp('2019-11-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-11-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-11-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-11-01 00:00:00')], 
        'inivalid_nova_validade': [None, pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'), None, None, None], 
        'operacao': ['inclusao', 'alteracao', 'inclusao', 'alteracao', 'exclusao'], 
        'dh_processamento_rubrica': [pd.Timestamp('2020-03-18 23:58:14'), pd.Timestamp('2020-05-14 17:27:06'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-07 23:46:07'), pd.Timestamp('2021-07-15 19:57:42'), pd.Timestamp('2021-08-13 15:31:56')]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

As per the data, "inclusao" adds a new entry, "alteracao" modifies existing entries, and "exclusao" removes entries. Each "alteracao" references the original entry it modifies by the inivalid_iderubrica attribute. The modifications can either update existing attributes or change the inivalid_iderubrica.

In the example:

1. A new entry (i) is added with inivalid_iderubrica == 2019-11-01
2. Entry (i) is updated to now have inivalid_iderubrica == 2019-01-01
3. A new entry (ii) is added with inivalid_iderubrica == 2019-11-01
4. Entry (i) is updated to change codinccp_dadosrubrica from 11 to 00
5. Entry (ii) is deleted

I need to determine the final state of each entry after all the operations have been applied, considering that the modifications are sequential (according to the dates on "dh_processamento_rubrica") and may affect subsequent operations.

Final state should something look like:

| codinccp_dadosrubrica | inivalid_iderubrica | inivalid_nova_validade | operacao | dh_processamento_rubrica |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | 2019-01-01 | NaT | alteracao | 2021-07-15 19:57:42 |

**Edit:**

I have the following solution using iterrows, which works but is unfortunately too slow, as I need to process DataFrame which sometimes may have millions of rows:

```py
df = df.sort_values(by=['dh_processamento_rubrica']).reset_index(drop=True)
df_alt_exc = df[df['operacao'] != 'inclusao']
df = df[df['operacao'] == 'inclusao']

for _, row in df_alt_exc.iterrows():
    to_update = df[(df['inivalid_iderubrica'] == row['inivalid_iderubrica'])]

    if row['operacao'] == 'alteracao':
        if to_update.size > 0:
            if not pd.isna(row['inivalid_nova_validade']):
                row['inivalid_iderubrica'] = row['inivalid_nova_validade']
            index_to_update = to_update.index[0]
            df.loc[index_to_update] = row

    if row['operacao'] == 'exclusao':
        if to_update.size > 0:
            index_to_update = to_update.index[0]
            df = df.drop(index_to_update)
```

I need to know if there's a way of solving this using **vectorized operations** (or any other approach that would be similarly as efficient).

Comment: Could you provide the code you are using; what have you tired so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed challenging, since the series of operations is important, which makes it hard to use vectorised operations. An extra challenge is that unique IDs are mutable. Luckily I think it is still possible to write a vectorised solution.

The below solution relies on the fact that an `alteracao` operation that changes the unique ID contains all the up-to-date information about the record, such that we can consider it an `inclusao` and use the `inivalid_nova_validade` as the new `inivalid_iderubrica`. We then group by unique IDs and take the `last` row which is not `exlucsao`, relying on the fact that the dataframe is ordered. Finally we search for IDs which are deleted (`exclusao`) or removed implicitly by having `inivalid_iderubrica` modified altered, and remove them from the final result.

Additional optimisation - converting the text column `operacao` to a `Categorical` to [save memory](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#categorical-memory).

Hopefully this works for your purposes.

```py
# sorting, from OP
df = df.sort_values(by=['dh_processamento_rubrica']).reset_index(drop=True)

# conversion to Categorical dtype - not strictly necessary, but saves memory
df["operacao"] = pd.Categorical(df["operacao"])

# check for deleted IDs. deletion means either `exclusao`, or having their `inivalid_iderubrica` replaced
deleted = df["operacao"].eq("exclusao")
deleted |= (df["operacao"].eq("alteracao")) & (~df["inivalid_nova_validade"].isna())

# if their final status is deleted, we will drop them at the end
final_status = deleted.groupby(df["inivalid_iderubrica"]).last()
excluded = final_status[final_status].index

# Wherever the `alteracao` changes the unique ID, consider it a new `inclusao` operation instead
alter_inivalid_mask = (df["operacao"].eq("alteracao")) & (~df["inivalid_nova_validade"].isna())
df.loc[alter_inivalid_mask, "inivalid_iderubrica"] = df.loc[alter_inivalid_mask, "inivalid_nova_validade"]
df.loc[alter_inivalid_mask, "inivalid_nova_validade"] = "NaT"
df.loc[alter_inivalid_mask, "operacao"] = "inclusao"

# get the final state for each unique ID, except when that state is `exclusao`
res = df[df["operacao"].ne("exclusao")].groupby("inivalid_iderubrica", dropna=False).last().reset_index()

# now to remove those that have final status of excluded
res = res[~res["inivalid_iderubrica"].isin(excluded)]
```

Yielding:

```
    inivalid_iderubrica     codinccp_dadosrubrica   inivalid_nova_validade  operacao    dh_processamento_rubrica
0   2019-01-01                       00                        NaT          alteracao   2021-07-15 19:57:42
```

Comment: That's a clever approach! Unfortunately, while it seems to return the correct result for the sample df, it doesn't always work. Operation `alteracao` must replace the corresponding `inclusao`. In my initial example, when the first entry is updated to have `inivalid_iderubrica` == 2019-01-01, the first line (with operation `inclusao`) should be removed.

Comment: In your answer it ends up being removed because of operation `exclusao` on the last row, when in reality it should have been removed as a result of the first operation `alteracao`. This is relevant because if we didn't have the last row (which refers to the second entry, and not the first), the first entry would be duplicated with conflicting attributes.

Comment: Not correct, it is replaced because we do `groupby.last`. We only take the last row for this `inivalid_iderubrica`.

Comment: `groupby.last` will get the last row for each group, but there are two groups in the same entry at that point: one group for `inivalid_iderubrica` `2019-01-01` and a another for `2019-11-01`.  This second group shouldn't exist.

Comment: You'll see what I mean if you use just the first two rows of the sample df. Both rows will remain in the result.

Comment: I see now, you are right. I have modified it to deal with this case, let me know if it works

Comment: Perfect! I replaced the second `groupby` with `drop_duplicates` because it was faster in tests with larger DataFrames, but other than that your answer is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have your comparisons built already; turn your if statement into a function and then use df.apply to call it against the rows you need changed.

Something like:

```
 #compare function
 def check_op():
  if operacao == 'inclusao':
    ...
  return 

#apply function to dataframe
data['codinccp_dadosrubrica'] = data['operacao'].apply(check_op())
```

Sources:

- [Pandas Documentation on .apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply)
- [SO post on how to apply functions to specific rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962104/how-can-i-use-the-apply-function-for-a-single-column).

Comment: This does not work (or maybe I couldn't get it to work), as it would not change the rows sequentially (which is a requirement). In any case, it would still be too slow, as df.apply is not vectorized (see my updated question, I need something that uses vectorized operations due to efficiency needs). I appreciate you taking the time to answer though.