# Create a new pandas column with a value from a user-defined function

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting a SettingWithCopyWarning when attempting to create a new column on a pandas dataframe using a function I created to return a value for that new column. I am using the movielens dataset and predicting the rating of a user on a movie.

This is an example of my dataframe:

[image]

Now if I want to add a new column called 'prediction' that sends the user_id and item_id to my function and return the prediction I have followed the advice of this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914937/applying-function-with-multiple-arguments-to-create-a-new-pandas-column)

Hence using the code:

```
df['pred'] = df.apply(lambda x: predict_rating(x['user_id'], x['item_id']), axis =1)
```

Yet I keep getting the SettingWithCopyWarning.

*:44: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy*

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Are you sure the warning doesn't come from your function predict_rating ? If it is, can you post the problematic part ?

Comment: What do you do before that line? You can get that warning if `df` was created from another dataframe before that without an explicit `.copy()`.

Comment: @Tbaki no because when I set the predict_rating function to be;
def predict_rating(item,user): return item,user it gives the same error

Comment: @EFT the code to create this df is:
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:4]]

Comment: @ajscriv it could means you tried to assign a value to x['user_id'], pandas tells you that if it's better for assignation use something like https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html

Can you give a reproductible exemple for us to play arround ?

Answer (score 0):

Do this ,

df.loc[:,'pred'] = df.apply(lambda x: predict_rating(x['user_id'], x['item_id']), axis =1)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with this minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[22,224], 'item_id': [377,29], 'rating': [1,3]})
def prediction_func(row):
    return row['user_id'] + row['item_id']

df['prediction'] = df.apply(prediction_func, axis=1)
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
   item_id  rating  user_id  prediction
0      377       1       22         399
1       29       3      224         253
```

Comment: This gives the error mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @ajscriv please tell me what python version you use

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with my function after all so will dig into that and report anything interesting.