# Multiple input and multiple output function application to Pandas DataFrame raises shape exception

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 6 columns (excluding the index), 2 of which are relevant inputs to a function and that function has two outputs. I'd like to insert these outputs to the original dataframe as columns.

I'm following toto_tico's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46197147/5754828). I'm copying for convenience (with slight modifications):

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30], "B": [20, 30, 10], "C": [10, 10, 10], "D": [1, 1, 1]})
    def fab(row):                                                  
        return row['A'] * row['B'], row['A'] + row['B']
    df['newcolumn'], df['newcolumn2'] = zip(*df.apply(fab, axis=1))
```

This code works without a problem. My code, however, doesn't.  My dataframe has the following structure:

```
        Date  Station  Insolation  Daily Total  Temperature(avg)  Latitude
0 2011-01-01  Aksaray         1.7      72927.6         -0.025000   38.3705
1 2011-01-02  Aksaray         5.6     145874.7          2.541667   38.3705
2 2011-01-03  Aksaray         6.3     147197.8          6.666667   38.3705
3 2011-01-04  Aksaray         2.9     100350.9          5.312500   38.3705
4 2011-01-05  Aksaray         0.7      42138.7          4.639130   38.3705
```

The function I'm applying takes a row as input, and returns two values based on Latitude and Date. Here's that function:

```
def h0(row):
    # Get a row from a dataframe, give back H0 and daylength
    # Leap year must be taken into account
    
    # row['Latitude'] and row['Date'] are relevant inputs
    
    # phi is taken in degrees, all angles are assumed to be degrees as well in formulas
    # numpy defaults to radians however...
    
    gsc = 1367
    phi = np.deg2rad(row['Latitude'])
    date = row['Date']
    
    year = pd.DatetimeIndex([date]).year[0]
    month = pd.DatetimeIndex([date]).month[0]
    day = pd.DatetimeIndex([date]).day[0]
    
    if year % 4 == 0:
        B = (day-1) * (360/366)
    else:
        B = (day-1) * (360/365)
    
    B = np.deg2rad(B)
    delta = (0.006918 - 0.399912*np.cos(B) + 0.070257*np.sin(B)
                           - 0.006758*np.cos(2*B) + 0.000907*np.sin(2*B)
                           - 0.002697*np.cos(3*B) + 0.00148*np.sin(3*B))
    
    ws = np.arccos(-np.tan(phi) * np.tan(delta))
    daylenght = (2/15) * np.rad2deg(ws)
    
    if year % 4 == 0:
        dayangle = np.deg2rad(360*day/366)
    else:
        dayangle = np.deg2rad(360*day/365)
    
    h0 = (24*3600*gsc/np.pi) * (1 + 0.033*np.cos(dayangle)) * (np.cos(phi)*np.cos(delta)*np.sin(ws) + 
                                                                     ws*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(delta))
    
    return h0, daylenght
```

When I use

```
ak['h0'], ak['N'] = zip(*ak.apply(h0, axis=1))
```

I get the error: Shape of passed values is (1816, 2), indices imply (1816, 6)

I'm unable to find what's wrong with my code. Can you help?

Comment: In the function itself, what if you do `row['h0'] = h0` and `row['N'] = daylenght` and then `return row`? And then your last line will just be `ak = ak.apply(h0, axis=1)`

Comment: @Orenshi thanks, your suggestion works. I don't know why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as mentioned in my previous comment, if you'd like to create multiple NEW columns in the DataFrame based on multiple EXISTING columns of the DataFrame. You can create a new field in the row Series WITHIN your `h0` function.

Here's an overly simple example to showcase what I mean:

```
>>> def simple_func(row):
...     row['new_column1'] = row.lat * 1000
...     row['year'] = row.date.year
...     row['month'] = row.date.month
...     row['day'] = row.date.day
...     return row
...
>>> df
        date   lat
0 2018-01-29  1000
1 2018-01-30  5000
>>> df.date
0   2018-01-29
1   2018-01-30
 Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> df.apply(simple_func, axis=1)
        date   lat  new_column1  year  month  day
0 2018-01-29  1000      1000000  2018      1   29
1 2018-01-30  5000      5000000  2018      1   30
```

In your case, inside your `h0` function, set`row['h0'] = h0` and `row['N'] = daylength` then `return row`. Then when it comes to calling the function the DF your line changes to `ak = ak.apply(h0, axis=1)`

Comment: I replied to your comment above as well, but can you elaborate on the distinction between toto_tico's way and yours? Why one works while the other doesn't?

Comment: It might have to do with how `.apply` works. It has to infer the shape of the output data and map it to the input DataFrame shape. The example that toto_tico did was a pretty simple one so it didn't have trouble guessing the shape. 

Check out this Pandas issue https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15628

Comment: By the way, I know your function is a bit complex, but if it's possible... try to refactor your code and get it to use more vectorization.

Comment: I though of vectorization, but first wanted to write a simple function that works. If the leap year thing wasn't there, vectorization would have been really easy. That includes an if clause referencing year which modifies the daily equations slightly. I don't how I can express that in vectorized code. (Month line is completely irrelevant, I forgot it there.)