# Create a new column from two existing columns applying a generic function (x,y) so that I can use the function with different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, dataframe, apply

I am trying to calculate a discount that I would like to apply to each row of two columns of my dataframe and add the result to a new column.

I have already tried many ways, by following existing examples, but everytime an error occurs.

I define the function as:

```
def delta_perc(x,y):
    if y == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (x-y)/x*100
```

and then try to apply the function to my dataframe

```
ordini["discount"] = ordini.apply(delta_perc(ordini["revenue1"],ordini["revenue2"]), axis=1)
```

I expected a new column where each row was the result of the function applied to ordini["revenue1"] and ordini["revenue2"].

But I get the following error:

**ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

I also tried to apply all the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914937/applying-function-with-multiple-arguments-to-create-a-new-pandas-column) but everytime an error occured.

Comment: Are you sure it's when `y==0` and not `x==0` that you return 0, given that you divide by `x`, which leads to `np.inf`?

Comment: Sure! While I was focusing on the second part of the code I was making that bigger mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a few concepts mixed up.  When you use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` (with `axis=1`) you are iterating through each row and passing that row (as a `pandas.Series` object) to the function you used when you called `apply`.

#### First Point of Failure

Instead, you are calling your function inside the `apply` and passing two columns to the function.  This will pass the return value of the function to the `apply`.  Since your function does not pass back a callable object, this should fail.

#### Second Point of Failure

Also, your function is designed to look at scalar values hence `if y == 0:` and when you pass column like `ordini["revenue1"]` (which is a `pandas.Series` object) it tries to evaluate `if pandas.Series == 0:` and that is what is generating the error you see:

> ```
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
> ```

---

#### Approach #1

Fix your function and don't use `apply`

```
def delta_perc(x, y):
    return x.sub(y).div(x).mask(x == 0, 0).mul(100)

ordini["discount"] = delta_perc(ordini["revenue1"], ordini["revenue2"])
```

---

#### Approach #2

Fix your funciton and use `map`.  This would be similar to using a comprehension.

```
def delta_perc(x, y):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (x - y) / x * 100

ordini["discount"] = [*map(delta_perc, ordini["revenue1"], ordini["revenue2"])]
```

---

#### Approach #3

Actually using `apply`

```
def delta_perc(x, y):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (x - y) / x * 100

# Because remember `apply` takes a function that gets a row (or column) passed to it
ordini["discount"] = ordini.apply(
    lambda row: delta_perc(row['revenue1'], row['revenue2']),
    axis=1
)
```

Comment: Thanks! You have given me really precious insights!

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
ordini["discount"] = [delta_perc(a,b) for a,b in zip(ordini["revenue1"],ordini["revenue2"])]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should apply this calculation to entire Series with `np.where`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def delta_perc(x, y):
    return np.where(y != 0, (x-y)/x*100, 0)
    # I think you may want when x != 0, since you divide by x: 
    #return np.where(x != 0, (x-y)/x*100, 0)
```

#### Example:

```
np.random.seed(12)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(10,2)))

df['new_col'] = delta_perc(df[0], df[1])
#   0  1     new_col
#0  6  1   83.333333
#1  2  3  -50.000000
#2  3  0    0.000000
#3  6  1   83.333333
#4  4  5  -25.000000
#5  9  2   77.777778
#6  6  0    0.000000
#7  5  8  -60.000000
#8  2  9 -350.000000
#9  3  4  -33.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `lambda` inside `apply` like this ?

```
ordini["discount"] = ordini.apply(
    lambda x: delta_perc(x["revenue1"], x["revenue2"]), axis=1
)
```

Try this, if performance matters to you.

```
import numpy as np

delta_perc_vec = np.vectorize(delta_perc)
ordini["discount"] = delta_perc_vec(df["revenue1"].values, df["revenue2"].values)
```