# How to split a pandas dataframe column into multiple using apply?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to easily split my column into two (or more) using apply. (I could use split like they do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns), but there are exceptions that would difficult to handle.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914937/applying-function-with-multiple-arguments-to-create-a-new-pandas-column) answer is similar, but again outputs one column.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"xVal":[1,2,7,4], "xRef":["1-2","2-3",">4", "NoReference"]})

def sep_ref(row):
    if '-' in row:
        return row.split("-")
    else:
        # handle and return some list
        return [row, row]

# broken assinment
df['xlow'], df['xhigh'] = df.xRef.apply(sep_ref)
```

df

```
   xVal            xRef
0     1           '1-2'
1     2           '2-3'
2     7            '>4'
3     4   'NoReference'
```

desired output

```
   xVal  xlow  xhigh
0     1     1      2
1     2     2      3
2     7     4    NaN
3     4   NaN    NaN
```

The easy solution is to run two separate apply functions, but this is less elegant and could make exception handling more difficult. Is there a way to append 2 columns at once with apply?

Comment: Can you explain better the logic when `-` is not present? Why you have `-4` and `NaN` for the 3rd row, and `NaN` and `Nan` for the 4th?

Comment: The idea is that my function (sep_ref) here could be an implementation with error handling, (at the basic level use conditionals to determine what to return. if row[0] == '>': return [row[1], NaN]). In the question I want to show that a basic [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns) is not my desired solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed the NaN preferences. Here is a fix:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"xVal":[1,2,7,4], "xRef":["1-2","2-3",">4", "NoReference"]})

def sep_ref(row):
    if '-' in row:
        return [int(x) for x in row.split("-")]
    elif row.startswith('>'):
        return [int(row[1:]), np.nan]
    elif row.startswith('<'):
        return [np.nan, int(row[1:])]
    else:
        return [np.nan, np.nan]

# not broken assinment
df['xlow'] = None
df['xhigh'] = None
df[['xlow', 'xhigh']] = [*df.xRef.apply(sep_ref)]
print(df)
```

```
   xVal         xRef  xlow  xhigh
0     1          1-2   1.0    2.0
1     2          2-3   2.0    3.0
2     7           >4   4.0    NaN
3     4  NoReference   NaN    NaN
```

---

**ORIGINAL:**

To do this, I think you need to initialize "xlow" and "xhigh" columns first.

```
# not broken assignment
df['xlow'] = None
df['xhigh'] = None
df[['xlow', 'xhigh']] = [*df.xRef.apply(sep_ref)]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   xVal         xRef         xlow        xhigh
0     1          1-2            1            2
1     2          2-3            2            3
2     7           >4           >4           >4
3     4  NoReference  NoReference  NoReference
```

Comment: What exactly is happening in "[*return_list]" that makes it compatible for the assignment when "return_list" doesn't work. Shouldn't the latter set the new columns values to the sep_ref return on the first row? (ie 'xlow':[1,1,1,1] and 'xhigh':[2,2,2,2])

Comment: In your case, the problem with `Series.apply` is that it always returns a Series that is analogous to a list of lists of lists (e.g. `[[[1, 2]], [[2, 3]], ...]`). It's basically a 3-D construct trapped inside a 1-D Series. To get around that, I *'d it to make it a true list of lists (e.g. `[[1, 2], [3, 4], ...])` -- a 2-D construct that can fill two columns.