# user defined function returns error in python

Tags: python, pandas

```py
    import pandas as pd
    d = {'a': [1,2,3],
         'b': [3,4,5],
         'c': [5,4,3]}
    df=pd.DataFrame(d)
    df
```

returns:

```
        a   b   c
    0   1   3   5
    1   2   4   4
    2   3   5   3
```

I create the following function to calculate m:

```py
    def foo(x,y,z):
        m=x(y+z)
        return m
```

Then apply it to df:

```py
    df['new']=df[['a', 'b', 'c']].apply(lambda x,y,z: foo(x,y,z))
```

but this gives following error:

```py
    ("<lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'", 'occurred at index a')
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: What is the purpose of the x variable ?

Comment: after you solve your problem, just want to point out that `x(y+z)` is calling `x` like a function, you probably want `x*(y+z)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems, 1 is a syntax error where you seem to forget the `*` operator:

```py
m=x(y+z)
```

should be:

```py
m=x*(y+z)
```

The more important one is about how you are distributing the arguments into the `foo` function via `lambda`. You can fix it with this solution:

```
df['new']=df.apply(lambda x: foo(x['a'],x['b'],x['c']),axis=1)
```

see also [Applying function with multiple arguments to create a new pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914937/applying-function-with-multiple-arguments-to-create-a-new-pandas-column)

Comment: Thank you all! fixed the x*(y+z) like Tadhg McDonald-Jensen said and applied df['new']=df.apply(lambda x: foo(x['a'],x['b'],x['c']),axis=1) like Raphael suggested and it all works now ^-^ seems i can't select both answers as correct :(