# Most efficient way to apply function to data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large data frame full of song lyrics. I've tokenized the lyrics column so each row is a list of lyrics, i.e. `["You", "say", "goodbye", "and", "I", "say", "hello"]` and so on. I wrote a function to calculate the sentiment score using a list of positive words and negative words. I then need to apply this function to the lyrics column to calculate positive sentiment, negative sentiment, and net sentiment and make them new columns.

I attempted to split my data frame into a list of chunks of 1000 and then loop through to apply, but it is still taking a fairly long time. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way that I should be doing this, or if this is as good as it gets and I just have to wait it out.

```
def sentiment_scorer(row):  
    pos=neg=0
    for item in row['lyrics']:
        # count positive words
        if item in positiv:
            pos += 1
        # count negative words
        elif item in negativ:
            neg += 1
        # ignore words that are neither negative nor positive
        else:
            pass
    # set sentiment to 0 if pos is 0
    if pos < 1:
        pos_sent = 0
    else:
        pos_sent = pos / len(row['lyrics'])
    # set sentiment to 0 if neg is 0
    if neg < 1:
        neg_sent = 0
    else:
        neg_sent = neg / len(row['lyrics'])
    # return positive and negative sentiment to make new columns
    return pos_sent, neg_sent

# chunk data frames
n = 1000  
list_df = [lyrics_cleaned_df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,lyrics_cleaned_df.shape[0],n)]

for lr in range(len(list_df)):
    # credit for method: toto_tico on Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/46197147
    list_df[lr]['positive_sentiment'], list_df[lr]['negative_sentiment'] = zip(*list_df[lr].apply(sentiment_scorer, axis=1))
    list_df[lr]['net_sentiment'] = list_df[lr]['positive_sentiment'] - list_df[lr]['negative_sentiment']
```

ETA: sample data frame

```
data = [['ego-remix', 2009, 'beyonce-knowles', 'Pop', ['oh', 'baby', 'how']], 
        ['then-tell-me', 2009, 'beyonce-knowles', 'Pop', ['playin', 'everything', 'so']], 
        ['honesty', 2009, 'beyonce-knowles', 'Pop', ['if', 'you', 'search']]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['song', 'year', 'artist', 'genre', 'lyrics'])
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of your dataframe? A lot of the the code in your function can be done using pandas/numpy.

Comment: @Josmoor98 added to question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly and using your example (I added a few more words to create uneven length lists). You can create a separate dataframe `lyrics`, converting the words from your lyrics into separate columns.

```
data = [['ego-remix', 2009, 'beyonce-knowles', 'Pop', ['oh', 'baby', 'how', "d"]], 
        ['then-tell-me', 2009, 'beyonce-knowles', 'Pop', ['playin', 'everything', 'so']], 
        ['honesty', 2009, 'beyonce-knowles', 'Pop', ['if', 'you', 'search']]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['song', 'year', 'artist', 'genre', 'lyrics'])
```

Then define `lyrics`.

```
lyrics = pd.DataFrame(df.lyrics.values.tolist())

#           0            1       2      3
# 0        oh         baby     how      d
# 1    playin   everything      so   None   # Null rows need to be accounted for 
# 2        if          you  search   None   # Null rows need to be accounted for
```

Then, if you have two lists with your positive and negative sentiment words, like below, you can to calculate the sentiment per row (lyric), using the `mean()` method.

```
# positive and negative sentiment words
pos = ['baby', 'you']
neg = ['if', 'so']

# When converting the lyrics list to a new dataframe, it will contain Null values
# when the length of the lists are not the same. Therefore these need to be scaled 
# according to the proportion of null values
null_rows = lyrics.notnull().mean(1)

# Calculate the proportion of positive and negative words, accounting for null values
pos_sent = lyrics.isin(pos).mean(1) / null_rows 
neg_sent = lyrics.isin(neg).mean(1) / null_rows 

# pos_sent
# 0    0.250000
# 1    0.000000
# 2    0.333333

# neg_sent 
# 0    0.000000
# 1    0.333333
# 2    0.333333
```

If I understand your problem fully, then you should be able to use `df['pos'] = pos_sent` and `df['neg'] = neg_sent`. I imagine there may be some issues, so let me know if this is in the right ball park.