# Creating multiple pandas columns from function returning dict

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a function that returns a dict object and I would like to take advantage of pandas/numpy's ability to perform columnwise operations/vectorization for this function across every row of a dataframe. The inputs for the function are specified in the dataframe and I want the outputs of the function to become new columns on the existing dataframe. Below is an example.

```
def func(a, b, c):
    return {
        "a_calc": a * 2, 
        "b_calc": b * 3, 
        "c_calc": c * 4
    }
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"a":1, "b":2, "c": 3}, {"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6}])
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Desired Output:

```
   a  b  c  a_calc  b_calc  c_calc
0  1  2  3       2       6      12
1  4  5  6       8      15      24
```

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46197147/9837010) and it got most of the way there but I couldn't quite figure out how to do it for when the function returns a dict object with the desired column names as the keys within the dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use some dataframe unpacking:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(func(**df)))
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  a_calc  b_calc  c_calc
0  1  2  3       2       6      12
1  4  5  6       8      15      24
```

Or really getting cute:

```
df.assign(**func(**df))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot modify your function, you can do:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(func(df['a'], df['b'],df['c']), index=df.index))
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  a_calc  b_calc  c_calc
0  1  2  3       2       6      12
1  4  5  6       8      15      24
```

**Note** We exploit the fact that `func` can accept series input and works in parallel.  In the general case, you need a `for` loop:

```
pd.DataFrame([func(x['a'], x['b'], x['c']) for _, x in df.iterrows()],
              index=df.index)
```

Comment: In my case, `func()` cannot accept series data. Is there any other way besides using `.iterrows()`?

Comment: @AustinUlfers Can you rewrite your function to accept a pd.Series?

Comment: @ScottBoston Its a relatively long function so I would like to avoid having to rewrite it if possible.

Comment: @AustinUlfers I think the only other way is to use lambda with axis=1 which is woefully slow and inefficient.

Comment: @ScottBoston ok, good to know. I'll go down the rewriting path then because I need this to be quick.

Comment: @AustinUlfers `iterrows`, `apply`, vanilla `for` loop are essentially equivalent. You could avoid one or another, but in general you would need to use one.