# Pandas apply getting KeyError:

Tags: python, pandas, function

I was looking at this answer by [Roman Pekar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914937/applying-function-with-multiple-arguments-to-create-a-new-pandas-column) for using apply. I initially copied the code exactly and it worked fine. Then I used it on my df3 that is created from a csv file and I got a KeyError. I checked datatypes the columns I was using are int64, so that is okay. I don't have nulls. If I can get this working then I will make the function more complex. How do I get this working?

```
def fxy(x, y):
    return x * y

df3 = pd.read_csv(path + 'test_data.csv', usecols=[0,1,2])
print(df3.dtypes)
df3['Area'] = df3.apply(lambda x: fxy(x['Len'], x['Width']))
```

**Trace back**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "f:\...\my_file.py", line 54, in <module>
df3['Area'] = df3.apply(lambda x: fxy(x['Len'], x['Width']))
File "C:\...\frame.py", line 8833, in apply
return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")
File "C:\...\apply.py", line 727, in apply
return self.apply_standard()
File "C:\...\apply.py", line 851, in apply_standard
results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
File "C:\...\apply.py", line 867, in apply_series_generator
results[i] = self.f(v)
File "f:\...\my_file.py", line 54, in <lambda>
df3['Area'] = df3.apply(lambda x: fxy(x['Len'], x['Width']))
File "C:\...\series.py", line 958, in __getitem__
return self._get_value(key)
File "C:\...\series.py", line 1069, in _get_value
loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
File "C:\...\range.py", line 389, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Len'
```

I don't see a way to attach the csv file. Below is **Sample df3** if I save the below with excel as "CSV (Comma delimited)(*.csv) I get the same results.

| ID | Len | Width |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 170 | 4 |
| B | 362 | 5 |
| C | 12 | 15 |
| D | 42 | 7 |
| E | 15 | 3 |
| F | 46 | 49 |
| G | 71 | 74 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you miss the `axis=1` on `apply`:

```
df3['Area'] = df3.apply(lambda x: fxy(x['Len'], x['Width']), axis=1)
```

But in your case, you can just do:

```
df3['Area'] = df3['Len'] * df3['Width']
print(df3)

# Output
   ID  Len  Width  Area
0  A   170      4   680
1  B   362      5  1810
2  C    12     15   180
3  D    42      7   294
4  E    15      3    45
5  F    46     49  2254
6  G    71     74  5254
```