# pandas apply function with multiple inputs to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function I want to use to generate a new column

```
 def airport_to_country(a_code,country_dict):
     return country_dict[a_code]
```

Dataframe looks like this:

```
Rank  AirportCode
1   LAX
2   AUH
3   HBE
...
.
```

What I want to do I create another column so it would look like this

```
Rank  ACode  Country
1       LAX  North America
2       AUH  United Arab Emirates
3       HBE  Egypt
...
.
```

normally I would do this :

```
df['Country'] = df['Acode'].apply(airport_to_country))
```

But my function has 2 inputs, so I also need to give it the country_dict which is a Airport code to Country mapping

I was hoping this would work but its erroring as its looking for another input for the country

```
df['Country'] = df['Acode'].apply(airport_to_country(country_dict))
```

I looked at this example:
[Applying function with multiple arguments to create a new pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914937/applying-function-with-multiple-arguments-to-create-a-new-pandas-column)

But my function is a lookup in a dict and not a simple multiplication of variables. So I couldn't get it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some fiddling around I got it to work using that example:

```
df['country'] = df.apply(lambda x: airport_to_contry(x['a_code'],country_dict),axis = 1)
```

Comment: `df['a_code'].apply(airport_to_country, args=(country_dict,))` <-- The apply can be simplified to this.

Comment: Also, `df['a_code'].apply(airport_to_country, country_dict=country_dict)`

Comment: @ScottBoston just curious what does `country_dict=country_dict` do?

Comment: Passes externally define country_dict to the applied function as an argument for country_dict variable input.